# Unable to solve this issue while running npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

I cannot seem to make npm start work. Can someone please help me?
I get this:

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S36P.png)

This is my package JSON file:

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjfoR.png)

Comment: this is a problem with your library try and delete the node_modules folder then run  npm install again.  if it fails a second time that dependency is not good.  also make sure that you do not have any version miss matches by installing @latest

Comment: Add code an error messages as text not as image

Comment: Can you drop the error here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing node_modules and then running npm install?